# Load images in blackberry - Lwuit

Tags: connection, lwuit

I develop with lwuit to Nokia and Blackberry.
I try to load from internet some images.
In Nokia all work fine, but in blackberry i get IllegalArgumentException.

I found that problem is occurs in createImage(byte[] bytes, int offset, int len) function . The device Log tell me that  source function that occurs to fail is in  encode Image class.

Do Anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. This occurs because i use POST method. I think in case that we dont send parametes but use method POST is occurs to problem with Content-Length in header of http message and  this the reason that i recieve error(400 or 411)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to networking in Blackberry which is well documented. There are multiple suggested fixes (e.g. using deviceside=true) which work for some cases but fail for others. Explaining RIM networking problems is just too much for this post, but we did solve these issues for [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Comment: The Problem is more complicated. Another images are work and recieve in Blackberry image. the url are fine because that work on Nokia,Android and Iphone.

Comment: I found the problem. This occurs because i use post method. I think in case that we dont send parametes but usemethod POST is occurs to problem with Content-Length in header of http message and recieve error(400 or 411)